# Upgrading from symfony 2.1.7 to symfony 2.1.8

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I ran composer update command and it updated from symfony 2.1.7 to symfony 2.1.8. This is where my problem started. Now when I try to run any symfony console command, I get error as below:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\console on line 16
```

When I run my project in browser I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\DebugClassLoader' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\bootstrap.php.cache on line 542
```

Previously it was working all fine.

How do I fix this ?

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.1.7",
    "imagine/Imagine": ">=0.2.8",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "cbsi/doctrine2-nestedset": "dev-master",
    "exercise/htmlpurifier-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web"
}
}
```

Comment: Habe you updated the complete list of all symfony bundles?

Comment: yes I have updated please see my composer.json require statement.

Comment: It is sometimes worth a try to delete whatever's inside the `vendor` folder and run the `composer install` command again.

Answer (score 2):

If someone has the same error with sensio distribution bundle=5, then your problem should be [Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in app/console on line 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983632/fatal-error-class-symfony-component-console-input-argvinput-not-found-in-app)

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the composer (https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update)

```
composer self-update
```

Clear its cache, for Windows its in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Composer` (https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home)

And then run the update again.

Deleting the symfony2 cache folder manually might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap file wasn't rebuilt properly, the composer.json file should have a scripts entry that will ensure this task is done for you (unless you're running with the --no-scripts flag).

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
}
```

You can manually run the script that builds the bootstrap file by running the following command in your symfony directory:

```
php /vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

Comment: i have these lines in my composer.json