# Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in app/console on line 16

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I got a working symfony app, today I decided to do a `composer update`

the result of the `composer update` can ben found here https://github.com/allan-simon/oauth2-symfony2-vagrant-fosuserbundle/commit/dfa25593f79c5595ca4759803ec1e998091c68b9  (mostly change in minor version, note there's a change in version of symfony, but keeping it to 2.6 produce also the problems below)

And now after the upgrade I got this error

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                         
  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in /vagrant/app/console on line 16  
  .
```

- The content of the app/console has not changed
- I've tried deleting and recreating the bootstrap.cache no change
- In my vendor directory, I do have said `ArgvInput` class

Any idea on what can the problem be ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem was caused because my `composer.json` had the line

```
"sensio/distribution-bundle": ">=2.3.7",
```

So it was updating to the latest version (5.x at the time of writing) which is incompatible with the files structure of symfony 2.7 and below projects

instead I've put the line

```
"sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
```

and now it's working fine

more explanation here

https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/issues/243

Comment: If you still want to update to distribution bundle 5, you should follow those instructions:https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.8.md